# C# documentation and unused using(s)

Tags: c#, documentation, using

I have a piece of documentation that references a class located in another namespace using the `<see />` tag.

In order for Intellisense to know what the identifier refers to and have the class name colored in blue-ish within the comment, I need to add the right using statement, which makes sense.

However, Intellisense is also marking that using statement as being unused by fading it out, which could cause other users or some automatic code cleanup to remove it.

The problem is that, if that using statement is removed, Intellisense no longer recognizes the identifier in the documentation.

How could I solve this ? Thank you.

**EDIT** Some example :

Let :

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class Bar
    {
    }
}
```

And :

```
using Foo; // In use by the documentation, but faded out.

namespace Baz
{
    /// <summary>
    /// See <see cref="Bar"/>
    /// </summary>
    public class UsesBar
    {
    }
}
```

I'm using VS2017

Comment: Can you show an example? I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Also tell us the exact version of Visual Studio (which I assume you are using).

Comment: Code I used to test, which does work: https://pastebin.com/wi4BsXbR

Comment: I haven't tried it out; Do you also need the `using` if you use the fully qualified name, like `my.other.namespace.ReferencedType` instead of just `ReferencedType`?

Comment: @Fildor No, then you don't need the using.

Comment: @PatrickHofman for Intellisense, I mean. For usage in code, that's clear.

Comment: No repro using your code too. On VS 2019 (16.0.3).

Comment: @Fildor I understand.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Then that's the solution, isn't it? Use the fully qualified name in `<see />`?

Comment: @Fildor That is a workaround IMHO. VS shouldn't suggest to remove the `using`. That might be a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It seems to work properly using the fully qualified name, but it makes the code very unclear, especially if you reference things multiple times. Is there really no other way ? Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Well, if it is "used" in XML-Doc, only, should it require the `using`? Personally, I tend to be specific in `<see />` anyway, to avoid misunderstandings, but maybe that's just me. If you also have an actual usage in code, you'll need the `using` anyway ... hm. I'm not sure if I would consider it a bug.

Comment: @Fildor I agree, but the documentation also 'references' the class, Intellisense does pick that up quite well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the fully qualified name of the class within the xml comment for it be recognized by the VS IntelliSense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's ugly but it seems like there is no other way, so I'll go for that.